# I want to add an expression to an ASP.NET Page Control like 'datas are shown which between 10 to 20 '

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination, paging

I have an ASP.NET Page Control in GridView. it works normally but I want to add in bottom of the page an expression which gives knowlegde about which datas are shown.
I added the page codes in gridview tags :
    
    
this works normally but I want to add expression. How can I add a dynamic expression using C# server side codes??

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you give some code sample showing what you are doing, and what you are expect.

You can find usefull information here: [Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
<b><a href="../../Meslek/RandevuOnay.aspx?tc=<%# Eval("TCKIMLIKNO") %>&onay=0" target="_blank">Randevu&nbsp;Ver</a></b>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
   <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
   <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" />
</asp:GridView>

Comment: I cannot see anything from this. Edit your question and put it there

Comment: Sorry, I can not add images or block of code because of I have not enough badges.

Answer (score 0):

Use for Example

```
<div>
    From <%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %> to <%# DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString() %>
</div>
```

Or try such way : http://www.w3schools.com/ASPnet/showfile_c.asp?filename=try_webpages_cs_001

Comment: thanks for attention but it is not an answer from my question.